# Common image added in drawable folder doesn't get displayed in Samsung device - Android

Tags: android, android-layout, android-drawable

I have one single image with size 1.2MB and with 2436 * 1539 dimension.
I have added this image in single `drawable` folder instead of adding it in different drawable folders`(drawable-hdpi, drawable-xdpi, drawable-xxdpi, drawable-xxxdpi)`.

When I run my app in **Samsung SM-G7102** device, the image does not get displayed. The devices use `xhdpi` images. Also it gets displayed in every other device.

But when I add the image in `drawable-xxxhdpi` folder it works for this **Samsung SM-G7102** device too.

**As we know after adding the image in `xxxhdpi` Android runtime down samples it for all dpi devices.**
**But my question is why adding it in simple `drawable` folder doesn't work?**

Any help will be appreciated.
Thanks in advance.

Following is my .xml code for setting image:

```
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
        <android.support.v7.widget.AppCompatImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/background_image" />
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`res/drawable/` is a legacy directory that is equivalent to `res/drawable-mdpi/`.

Android, therefore, will upscale the image when loading it into an `-xhdpi` device. That's a 2x increase per dimension, so your resulting image would be 4872 * 3078. That is ~57MB as an `ARGB_8888` image, and you probably ran out of memory.

Comment: So should I add the image in `res/drawable-xxxhdpi/` as Android will downsample it?

Comment: @Kavita_p: Either that, or put it in `res/drawable-nodpi/`. Then Android will not downsample it (or upsample it), but instead will leave it alone.

Comment: yes, downsampling and upsampling take time to get processed as the operation get performed run time. So it's better to add the image in `drawable-nodpi` folder. Thanks for the help.